# AngularJS $http get method returns "Array" instead of the array's content

Tags: php, angularjs, http, get, ionic-framework

1st please excuse my english I'm french ;)

I'm facing a problem I don't understand despite a lot of web research. I'm sure someone more skilled than me could help me because I'm still a student.

I'm doing an **http get** from an **Angular** application but the data returned is the string "Array" instead of the array's content.
Here's my code :

```
app.controller('WatchCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getAll = function(){
      $http.get('http://www.myserver.com/videos/script.php')
        .then(function(response){
          $scope.videos = response.data;
          console.log(response); //to debug
        });
    }
    $scope.getAll();
  });
```

On the server side, my php script is just doing an **echo ['a', 'b', 'c']** so as to test. If I echo a string like "hello", I'm able to manipulate it on my client side but as soon as this is an array the response's data property is just "Array".

The console doesn't show any error message. To be noted I put a **header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")** in my script in order to accept cross origin. I don't know if it's playing a role in this scenario.

Comment: `echo ['a', 'b', 'c']` is array so server side is giving the text `Array`. Try `json_encode([a,b,c]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use echo to render an array so , use like this on server side :

```
print json_encode(array('a','b','c'));
```